# Passing more than one variable to Angular JS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to writing directives.  I have this snippet of code that works and I am trying to make it a directive:

```
<div ng-click="details=!details" class="row toggleHeader" ng-class="{open : details}">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <h4>Some title</h4>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="the-details" class="row" ng-show="details">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    ...content...
 </div>
</div>
```

So, my initial pass was

```
app.directive('pbTogglePanel', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                variableName: '@',
                panelTitle: '@'
            },
            template: '<div ng-click="somevariable=!somevariable" class="row toggleHeader" ng-class="{open : somevariable}">\n<div class="col-md-12">\n<h4>{{panelTitle}}</h4>\n</div>\n</div>\n\n<div id="the-somevariable" class="row" ng-show="somevariable">\n<div class="col-md-2">\n...\n</div>\n</div>',
        };
    });
```

with the html

```
 <div pb-toggle-panel panel-title="My Directive Panel Test" variable-name="foobar"></div>
```

This works, in the sense that the panel toggles as expected.  I obviously did not try to *use* the variable "foobar" passed from the html attribute.  When I try to use it, the code throws an error and the toggle does not work. I tried using the template:

```
'<div ng-click="{{variableName}}=!{{variableName}}" class="row toggleHeader" ng-class="{open : {{variableName}}}">\n<div class="col-md-12">\n<h4>{{panelTitle}}</h4>\n</div>\n</div>\n\n<div id="the-{{variableName}}" class="row" ng-show="{{variableName}}">\n<div class="col-md-2">\n...\n</div>\n</div>'
```

Although "foobar" shows up in all those places, the toggling fails and the console logs an angular error.

So, what's the correct way to pull in more than one html attribute?

Also, the goal would be to allow the contents of this DIV  to replace `...content...` placeholder in my template. Not sure how to pass that either.

I feel if I can just get my head around how this data is passed, I'll be good from there out.

**TO HELP CLARIFY**
This works: http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/MYygpy

But I wanted to pass the name of the variable for the toggler to use from an attribute too, and this does NOT work:
http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/KwzPaw

Comment: FYI you can use templateUrl: 'path/to/my/templates/view.html' instead of inlining the template in the directive - keeps the HTML a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes it a bit more complex when running build scripts in Gulp, so I try to avoid it.

Comment: If you changed your directive's template to `{{ variableName }} {{ panelTitle }}` you'd see the values passed from your HTML, right? maybe the problem isn't passing the values into the directive, but how you are using them once in your template? (this one is new to me: ng-class="{open : {{variableName}}}") Does the console error have anything useful in it?

Comment: Well, yes, as I said when you inspect the html it looks correct, the same as when it's hard-coded.  It doesn't seem to like the variable ("details" in my hard-code example) when it comes from a variable.  I get an error on load of  `Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$parse/syntax?p0=variableName&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=4&p3=%7B%7B%20variableName%20%7D%7D%3D!%7B%7B%20variableName%20%7D%7D&p4=variableName%20%7D%7D%3D!%7B%7B%20variableName%20%7D%7D`

Comment: this seems screwey to me `ng-class="{open : {{variableName}}}"` ng-class needs an expression which requires {{ variableName }} or something like that, right? what should { open: {{variableName}}} be doing? if you remove that it seems like your toggle should work.

Comment: No, look at the flat snippet at the top.  I add the class "open" to the div when the variable is true.  This is for CSS.  See this pen:http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/KwzPaw

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your last, non-working example is not about passing multiple parameters but rather abusing the angular's interpolation mechanism. If all you want is to use the `variableName`, the minimal change to make your last code example work (that is to collapse/expand) would be to change the template from string to function with concatenation:

```
{...
template: function(tElem, tAttr){return '<div ng-click="' + tAttr.variableName + '=!' + tAttr.variableName +...; 
}
```

But there is no point to do so as long as you use [directive isolating scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive), which effectively hides the value of the `variableName` from you. You will also probably want to change to `scope:false` and get attributes from the `tAttr` of the template function instead. [Modified example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyOBQV?editors=101).

Comment: I didn't think of doing it that way, thanks. I need to read up on directive scopes, it's very confusing.  Now I just need to figure out how to collect the contents on the html div and print it out at the appropriate spot in the template.

Comment: @Steve I totally agree scopes of the directives are confusing. I found this doc giving a good overview: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html